# How to bypass default drop policy in iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables

I am new to `iptables` and I need to block all HTTP/HTTPS traffic except to a certain IP (I am using below the IP of `example.com`).

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 93.184.216.34 --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 93.184.216.34 --sport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 93.184.216.34 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 93.184.216.34 --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

For the DNS resolution I also have:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -s 192.168.1.253 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

However, every time I set the default policies to `DROP` (`iptables -P INPUT DROP` etc.), I cannot access the IP despite my own rules. I have tried using `-m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED` but with no luck. What am I missing here?

Comment: What command(s) do you use to "set the default policies to `DROP`"? Please [edit] the question and add this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am I missing here?

Probably you're confusing source and destination big time. Maybe not `-s` and `-d`, but rather `--sport` and `--dport`.

In the `OUTPUT` chain you deal with packets generated on your machine (source) and going to elsewhere (destination). In the `INPUT` chain you deal with packets generated elsewhere (source) and incoming to your machine (destination). Options like `-s`, `--sport`, `-d` and `--dport` test respective **s**ource or **d**estination.

Let's analyze one of your rules:

> ```
> iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 93.184.216.34 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
> ```

It means you're accepting incoming packets generated by `93.184.216.34` and destined to the TCP port `80` *on your machine*, as if you hosted a HTTP server. The next rule:

> ```
> iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 93.184.216.34 --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
> ```

would allow your server to respond. But then you said "I cannot access the IP despite my own rules", so I think your goal is to reach the HTTP server on `93.184.216.34` and the HTTP server (if any) on your machine was not on your mind at all. If so, then you should first allow your machine to reach the remote server:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 93.184.216.34 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

In the gist of your example the following line would allow your machine to get the response:

```
# not the best idea though, see below
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 93.184.216.34 --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

But imagine there is a server listening on your machine (not necessarily HTTP, any server using TCP) and you set other `iptables` rules to allow only one or few trusted IP addresses to connect. An attacker controlling `93.184.216.34` may try to connect from its port `80` to your server and the above rule will accept the connection.

For this reason it's good to use `-m state` ([or `-m conntrack`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108169/108618)) to only allow packets from already `ESTABLISHED` connections to come in (and maybe `RELATED`, see `man 8 iptables-extensions` to learn what these names mean). This will accept packets belonging to connections your machine initiated, but not packets initiating new connections:

```
# not the most practical, see below
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 93.184.216.34 --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

In practice it's common to do this instead:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

The idea is it will not match totally foreign connections that are trying to get to your machine unprovoked, but it will accept the incoming half of any connection initiated by your machine or any connection related to what your machine initiated. Now use the `OUTPUT` chain to manage what can be initiated and the above rule will handle all responses.

E.g., assuming `192.168.1.253` is the DNS server, you allow your machine to reach it:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -d 192.168.1.253 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

and the generic rule in the `INPUT` chain will accept responses.

---

Knowing all this we can now introduce a snippet that should do what you want:

```
# assuming non-default tables (e.g. raw) don't interfere
iptables -P  INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -F
iptables -A  INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -d 192.168.1.253 --dport  53  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 93.184.216.34 --dport  80  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 93.184.216.34 --dport 443  -j ACCEPT
```

Additionally you may want to add rules that allow ICMP (`-p icmp`) or specific ICMP type(s) (`-p icmp --icmp-type …`) – useful for `ping`. I won't cover this subject here.